# Entity Framework Core : seed data error using OwnsOne

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm facing an issue while trying to seed data for the `Country` entity using Entity Framework Core.

My entity classes are set up as follows:

```cs
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Iso3 { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

public class Currency
{
    public Currency(string code, string name, string symbol)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        Symbol = symbol;
    }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

In my `DbContext`, I have set up the configuration for the `Country` entity using `EntityTypeConfiguration`, including a one-to-one relationship with the `Currency` entity:

```cs
public class CountryEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Country>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Country> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("countries");

        builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);

        builder.Property(e => e.Name)
               .HasMaxLength(100)
               .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(e => e.Iso3)
               .HasMaxLength(3)
               .IsRequired();

        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Currency, c => {
            c.Property(_ => _.Code)
             .HasMaxLength(3)
             .IsRequired();

            c.Property(_ => _.Name)
             .HasMaxLength(45)
             .IsRequired();

            c.Property(_ => _.Symbol)
             .HasMaxLength(10)
             .IsRequired();
        });
    }
}
```

My migration creates the table exactly as I expected:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "countries",
        columns: table => new
        {
            id = table.Column<int>(type: "integer", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityByDefaultColumn),
            name = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
            iso3 = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(3)", maxLength: 3, nullable: false),
            capital = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
            currency_code = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(3)", maxLength: 3, nullable: false),
            currency_name = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(45)", maxLength: 45, nullable: false),
            currency_symbol = table.Column<string>(type: "character varying(10)", maxLength: 10, nullable: false),
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("pk_countries", x => x.id);
        });
}
```

My seed:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasData(new Country { Id = 1, Name = "Afghanistan", Iso3 = "AFG", Currency = new Currency(code: "AFN", name: "Afghan afghani", symbol: "؋")});
```

However, when I try to seed data for the `Country` entity using the migration below, I get an error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Country' with the key value 'Id:1' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Currency' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'Currency' and specify the foreign key values {'CountryId'}.

I'm unsure how to resolve this error and successfully seed data for the `Country` entity with the related `Currency` data.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You're unfortunately not showing the code that seeds the data ....

Comment: this is a example @marc_s:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>().HasData(new Country { Id = 1, Name = "Afghanistan", Iso3 = "AFG", Currency = new Currency(code: "AFN", name: "Afghan afghani", symbol: "؋")});
```

Comment: Please - add this to our original question (by editing it), and properly format it - thanks!